# How do I configure the DbContext in an Autofac json configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, autofac, autofac-configuration

**ENV: VS 2019, C# .NET Framework 4.6.1**

I'm using a `.json` file to hold all my configurations:

```
IConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");
```

My question is, how do I include the `DbContext` in this file?  I'm adding Autofac to an existing application and using it in a new section.  This is what the code looks like (change the real name to "My*" to protect the innocent) in the original code:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public MyDbContext () : base("MyDB")
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {}
}
```

Is it possible to relate the `DbContext` concrete class to an existing interface (does one exist) or should I create a wrapper around it and then create a corresponding interface for the wrapper class?

Answer (score 0):

The typical practice is to put connection info (e.g. a connection string) into the configuration file, not the JSON representation of a service class such as a `DbContext`).

You can then inject the concrete context (or, [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66295085/64348), an [IDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) that creates the `MyDbContext`.

It becomes very problematic very quickly to provide non-configuration things in a configuration file (e.g. repos, service classes, EF resources, etc.) Stick to configuration alone.

Comment: Thanks.  Will try that out.